# Host node.js script online and monitor logs from a phone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this is a bit weird question, but I made a Node.js app which logs out some important information in the Terminal. Is there a way where I can host this app online and monitor logs when I am not at home?

Comment: Ideally you would need a web interface to go with this to fetch / parse the logs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I feel you almost made this connection, but this is typically referred to as 'hosting'. Just find a webhost that advertises support for node. There are many, and it seems inappropriate to make a specific endorsement.